# Spring MVC 4 + Thymeleaf: static resources 404 error

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, thymeleaf

I'm developing a webapp using Spring 4.3.4 + Spring MVC + Thymeleaf 3.0.2. By the way, I've not integrated Spring Security yet so there isn't any security policy in place.

The problem is simple: **the static resources are not loaded on browser (error 404)**.

This is my project folder structure, that is a standard maven structure (I've put static resources on ***/src/main/resources/static***, but i also tried ***/src/main/webapp/*** or ***/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/***):

[image]
And this is, for example, how I link CSS on my pages (trust me, the file ***/src/main/resources/static/assets/css/style.css*** really exists):

```
<link th:href="@{/assets/css/style.css}" type="text/css" />
```

As far as I know I shouldn't need a ResourceHandler to handle contents on ***/src/main/resourcess/static/assets/***, that should already be available at ***/assets/***, but it doesn't work, so in my spring java configuration I've also made also few tries like:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("classpath:/static/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("classpath:/static/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
}
```

In any case CSS and JS files are not accessible.

My dispatcher servlet is mapped to the root /:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myappDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I inspect HTML on browser I can see that the above  tag becomes:

```
<link href="/myapp/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

that looks pretty correct to me, right?

So, why do I receive a 404 error if I try to access the css? Am I forgetting something important?

Thank you,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem I needed to change my folder structure, moving static resources into ***/webapp/*** folder. I'm pretty sure there is a way to leave CSS and JS into ***/resources/*** folder, but I didn't make it work, so this is my new folder structure:

[image]

Then I've set the resource handler mapping:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
}
```

And this is the *link* tag used in the HTML template (that works both for dynamic and static loading of the page):

```
<link th:href="@{/assets/css/style.css}" href="../../assets/css/style.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

remove resource handler mappings,

then change to

```
<link th:href="@{/assets/css/style.css}" href="../static/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I've already tried with and without resource handler mappings, and the result is the same. Besides, your tag is exactly like mine, with the exception of the addition of the _href_ attribute, that it will be ignored by the thymeleaf engine during view rendering (it can only affects when you open the .html template statically).